# How can I get rid of the ListFormWebPart in a custom form?

Tags: custom-form, list-form-web-part, visual-studio

I'm pretty new to SP, but I had to bite the bullet and create a custom new form for a custom list schema. I mirrored the field structure with textboxes and such, added some custom javascript, validators and business logic, but my problem is that Sharepoint keeps injecting the old `ListFormWebPart` into my page. I can set the WebPartZone's `Visible` property to false and thus hide it, but I'd like to get rid of it altogether. Not to mention that, since its fields are all empty, my `Page.Valid` property will always return `false`.

Is there some code snippet that will do this job for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised how your page is working after deleting LFWP, because if I do it in the MOSS 2007 there will be exception. And the solution is not [simple](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dszabo/custom-list-newform-aspx-ruined-in-wss-3-0).

You just need to leave LFWP. Paste new custom list near it.
Don't know how to do it in Studio, in Office Designer you can do it as mentioned [there](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2007-5-Customize_the_-and-quot;NewFormaspx-and-quot;_page_for_a_SharePoint_List.aspx).
Just don't delete LFWP, you'd hide it, in Designer simply press right button and choose web-part property, then Hide in layout section.

Think you can do similar in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to popular belief (another SharePoint Myth), you can just delete the LFWP from the page entirely.  You can do this in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: The problem is, I'm developing a redistributable package in Visual Studio, and the form is coded from scratch. I can't even see the `ListFormWebPart`, it gets added to the `WebPartZone` behind the scenes.

Comment: Marc, you could add some meat to those bones as this is a very commonly held opinion.

Comment: Yes, it is, and it's a falacious opinion. I delete the default LFWP every single time and I have had zero issues.